# Instance Segmentation and Object Detection on C++ on custom dataset?

Tags: c++, yolo

I am aware that I can perform object detection, and instance segmentation on YOLO networks in C++, but only on the coco dataset. Is there a way I can run the YOLO network in C++ but trained on a custom dataset?